# .htaccess config so when I click a file it downloads it instead of viewing the contents

Tags: html, .htaccess

I have been trying to setup my .htaccess file for a while. I want it so when I go to a directory, lets say /tf/scripts/thisisfile.txt when I click it I want it to download instead of viewing the txt. Does anyone know how to  do this?

AddType application/octet-stream .avi .mpg .mov .pdf .xls .mp4 .txt

And:

Header set Content-Disposition attachment
Header set Content-Type application/octet-stream

And:

AddType application/octet-stream .csv
AddType application/octet-stream .xls
AddType application/octet-stream .doc
AddType application/octet-stream .avi
AddType application/octet-stream .mpg
AddType application/octet-stream .mov
AddType application/octet-stream .txt

Comment: Will edit the main post.

Comment: what OS is this running on. Have you tried to place the .htaccess file in that directory

Comment: Dont know the OS, but I will try putting the htaccess file in the directory of my files. Edit: Did not work.

Comment: Added an answer to place in .htaccess file in directory.

Comment: Did not work. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try this out,

Internet Explorer will usually try to show Microsoft Word files (doc and docx) in the browser, while most other browsers will download it.

To add consistency or to force certain files to download, you can fix this by simply adding an .htaccess file to the files directory. Note this only works with Public downloads and an Apache web server.

Set up a Specific Files to Download

First, setup your file field so that it saves into a separate directory. This will make it so that you will only force certain files to download and not affect the rest of the files on your Drupal site. Visit Administer -> Content management -> Content types (admin/content/types). Click "Manage fields" on the type that you want files to be forced to be downloaded. Add or edit a file field, under the "Path settings" fieldset, set a path for your files to be uploaded.
Now files uploaded to that field will be saved in a separate folder under your sites files directory.

FTP to your site and create a file named .htaccess in your files directory. Usually this will be sites/default/files/[name of the subdirectory from step 1]. In that file put the following lines:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:doc|odf|pdf|rtf|txt)$">
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

This particular example will force files with doc, odf, pdf, rtf, or txt to download instead of being shown in the browser.

Upload a few files and (using the "Generic files" display setting), the files will be downloaded when the user clicks on the link.
You may need to load mod_headers in Apache2 for this to work.
Assuming you have root access it can be done as follows:

```
# a2enmod headers
# /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

Comment: is there a link i can click on

Comment: majesticweb.us/tf/scripts/items/ and click on the mvm_upgrades.txt it wont download.

Comment: is this IE,  as i clicked on it in chrome and it went straight to download

Comment: Chrome. Does not download on my friends chrome too

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the download attribute for links.

```
//This is your link
<a href="myfile.txt" download>Click here to download my file</a>
```

Check this page for reference:
[W3 Schools Reference On HTML  Tag's Download Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp)

There you will see it says there are no restrictions on what files this can be applied to.

Comment: Will this make all txt files on my site download? I am using my host as a Fast Download server  for a video game and I need it to download hundreds of txt and cfg files. I want to be able to make all files that have a certain type download instead of being viewed in the browser. So, like if you click on /tf/tester.txt it will instantly prompt where to save it, and the same for all txt files.

Comment: No this will not do that, but my suggestion would be to use your server-side language to include the download tag when you are cycling through each item you are looking to make available for download.

Comment: Not sure if this will be efficient, you see I am doing it as a fast download server and I will have thousands of files sitting there for the video game to download,but from what I see it only downloads if you have it set the way I have described.

Comment: Ah yes, in that case it would better suit you to configure your server through your .htaccess file. However, If the other answer didn't help I'd suggest you look into what server specs you have, that should aid in finding the proper configuration.